# How to convert a local HTML file to PDF using Python in Windows?

Tags: python, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

If you have a local HTML file, how do you convert it to a PDF using Python on in a Windows environment?

A post suggested to use pdfkit but an error I kept receiving was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 21, in __init__
    with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\EXODUS\FolderRedirections\jarad.collier\My Documents\root\scripts\Jupyter Notebooks\convert_html_to_pdf.py", line 5, in <module>
    pdfkit.from_file('Two_Proportion_Hypothesis_Testing.html', 'out.pdf')
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 47, in from_file
    configuration=configuration, cover_first=cover_first)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.configuration = (Configuration() if configuration is None
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 27, in __init__
    'https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf' % self.wkhtmltopdf)
OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```